# How to execute some code based on ip address in javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, blogger

I am trying to make a premium version of my website and allowing only premium members to view some divs or hide ads, etc. I wanted to do it based on IP addresses. For that I searched the web and found this snippet:

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (userip== 0.0.0.0 || 1.1.1.1) { // More addresses as required. Given addresses are for example only
document. getElementsByClassName('ads-here'). style. display = "none";
}</script>
```

But as always the above code doesn't work. I tried to do `document.write` and the output comes perfectly fine. What seems to be the problem here. Please explain.

Note 1: I am still learning JavaScript.

Note 2: The platform of my website is Blogger (Idk if that matters)

Comment: Surely premium members have a login/user id? Be much better to do it based off that, rather than IP (for instance, I'd expect my reputation on here to transfer between my different devices, assuming I'm logged in).

Comment: the java tag on this isn't appropriate I think. At least it appears you are looking for a frontend-only solution.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion! I will surely check that out! Can you also suggest how I can make a login setup on blogspot. That would help out a ton!

Comment: Every user who can use developer tools is a premium user of this page. You need a server-side authoring system for this.

Comment: @Teemu I would consider this feature as a convenience, any person can use devtools to remove ads on any pages, whether it's server-sided or client-sided, the only difference is how it is automated and user-friendly.

Comment: @SohamWani - there'll likely be a blogspot guide for it; I'm not familiar with that particular platform.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `function()`. Your src not fully ready, so the `userip` is null `userip == 0.0.0.0` always be false.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
       if (userip== 0.0.0.0 || 1.1.1.1) { // More addresses as required. Given addresses are for example only
       document. getElementsByClassName('ads-here'). style. display = "none";
    }
    })();
    </script>
```

Edit: made it to work. Should first define `userip`. PS: Ublock Origin blocking l2.io.

```html
<div class="ads-here"> dsgdfgadf </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var userip;
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://l2.io/ip.js?var=userip"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function() {
  if (userip == '0.0.0.0') {
      document. getElementsByClassName('ads-here')[0].style.display = "none";
    }
      console.log(userip)
   })();
</script>
```

Comment: The script tag doesn't have the async attribute, so they should always be loaded in order.

Comment: Tried, it doesn't seem to work. Can you suggest an alternative?

Comment: @soshime will surely check that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your code, `document.getElementsByClassName('ads-here').style.display = "none";`, is incorrect because `getElementsByClassName` returns an `HTMLCollection`, not an `Element`. You will have to loop through the result of `document.getElementsByClassName('ads-here')` and set their `style.display` to `"none"`. Example:

```js
for (const element of document.getElementsByClassName('ads-here')) {
    element.style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Is the for loop inside if? Sry, I am a noob...

Comment: Yes, the for loop should be inside the if. The for loop is the corrected version of your code in `if`.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. I tried putting my ip instead of 0.0.0.0. what's the matter? I am sorry I am not good at it!

Comment: Hm, can you check if the `userip` variable is indeed equal to your ip?

Comment: Can you suggest an alternate code instead to achieve the goal?

Comment: yeah it is. I did check